# RibbonDropDownItems not visible after creating new mail

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

For every receiver the user types in the "To" field my add-in will create a corresponding `RibbonDropDown` item which I will add in a `RibbonGallery`. After the event is triggered the following code is executed:

```
private void updateGallery(string name, string address, string gender, double probability)
{
    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.RibbonUI.Invalidate();

    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonDropDownItem itemReceiver = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
    itemReceiver.ScreenTip = address;
    itemReceiver.Tag = gender;
    itemReceiver.Label = name;
    itemReceiver.SuperTip = (probability * 100).ToString() + " % Probability";

    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.gallery1.Items.Add(itemReceiver);
}
```

**Note:** *gallery1* is the `RibbonGallery`.

This is what the user is going to see:

[image: View (First Mail)]

As you can see in the first picture the UI works as intended. When the user is creating a new mail the gallery doesn't update its items anymore. The code will still be executed, but the new items will not be shown in the UI.

This is what the user is going to see:

[image: View (Every Mail after)]

I tried using `Invalidate`, but either I'm doing it wrong or/and it doesn't seem to work. The add-in also generates a salutation based on the contents of *gallery1*. In [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsroZ.png) you can see that the mail body creates a salutation, so the content of *gallery1* is legit but not shown at all.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="Smart Mail">
                <group id="groupUnsub" label="Unsubscribe">
                    <button id="btnUnsub" imageMso="JunkEmailOptions" onAction="button1_Click" supertip="Use this function to unsubscribe." label="Cancel Mailinglist" size="large" />
                </group>
                <group id="group1" label="Genderize">
                    <gallery id="gallery1" onAction="gallery1_Click" label="Identified Genders" size="large" columns="2" rows="2" itemHeight="32" itemWidth="32">
                        <button id="btnIndividualSalutation" imageMso="SendCopyOptions" onAction="btnIndividualSalutation_Click" label="Insert Individual Salutation" />
                        <button id="btnGroupSalutation" imageMso="SendCopyOptions" onAction="btnGroupSalutation_Click" label="Insert Group Salutation" />
                    </gallery>
                </group>
                <group id="group2" label="User Preferences">
                    <checkBox id="chkAutoSaveToContacts" onAction="chkAutoSaveToContacts_Click" label="Autosave to Contacts" />
                    <checkBox id="chkAutoAddSalutation" onAction="chkAutoAddSalutation_Click" label="Autoadd Salutation" />
                    <checkBox id="chkGroupSalutation" onAction="chkGroupSalutation_Click" label="Group Salutation" />
                    <checkBox id="chkAutoComplete" onAction="chkAutoComplete_Click" label="Autocomplete Text" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: @aduguid The event is triggered when the user has typed a recipient in to the "To" field

Comment: @aduguid I found something interesting. When I start Outlook and create 2 mails, leaving both windows open, and I type in a recipient in the second mail it somehow updates the `RibbonDropDown` from the window of the first mail. So, it only updates the UI in the first instance.

Comment: It sounds like the control isn't being invalidated. The invalidate method should be called from the event. The event should be raised in your ThisAddin.cs file.

Comment: I'll be able to take a look when I'm back in the office in about 8 hours.

Comment: It looks like it may be the `MailItem.PropertyChange` event you're after for when the "To" field is updated. Also, `Explorer.SelectionChange` may be the one for when focus changes from one message to another.